# [Flutter]How to import image from gallery dynamically

Tags: flutter

I am a new flutter learner and trying to create my first app. My problem is...

(1). I use a method to build a place(widget) for image which will come from gallery or camera.

```
    void _showPicker(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              child: new Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new ListTile(
                      leading: new Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                      title: new Text('Gallery'),
                      onTap: () {
                        _imgFromGallery();
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }),
                  new ListTile(
                    leading: new Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                    title: new Text('Camera'),
                    onTap: () {
                      _imgFromCamera();
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

(2). I created a method to import image by using `image_picker` package.

```
Future _imgFromGallery() async {
    final pickedImage =
        await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedImage != null) {
        this._image = new File(pickedImage.path);
      }
    });
  }
```

(3). I create a button which if pressed, will call method (1) and medthod (1) contained medthod (2).

(4). When I added the first image, everything fine but, when I add the second image, the first image also changed to the second

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN6Bc.png)

**So, could you please help me for figure out of this problem?**

Sorry that I didn't share the code that call _showPicker (function for displayed image) here is the code...please focus at `GestureDetector(...),`

```
_createListStepRow(String item, int index) {
    return Column(children: [
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
        child: Column(children: [
          Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 1175.0.w,
              child: TextField(
                  autofocus: this.autoFocus,
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.restaurant_outlined,
                      color: Constants.primaryColor,
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.5),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0),
                    ),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                    hintText: item,
                    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                  )),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _itemsStep.removeAt(index);
                });
              },
            ),
          ]),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              _showPicker(context);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              // height: 800.0.h,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                // image: DecorationImage(
                //   image: AssetImage('assets/images/food1.jpg'),
                //   fit: BoxFit.fill,
                // ),
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              ),
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    new Column(children: [
                      Container(
                        // height: 200.0.h,r
                        child: _image == null
                            ? _nullImage
                            : Image.file(_image, fit: BoxFit.contain),
                      ),
                      // Text(
                      //   'Click to Add Step Image',
                      //   style: GoogleFonts.poppins(fontSize: 14),
                      // ),
                    ]),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 60.0.h),
        ]),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 30.0.h),
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: Share your layout code when displaying an image.

Comment: You will have to share the code that contains how you're accessing the images that are being displayed. Please share it so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're not storing the images. You're basically choosing the latest one. Lets fix that. Find where you've declared `var _image;` and change that to `final List<File> _images;`.

Next, change the `Column` in the `GestureDetector` in `_showPicker` to this:

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    new ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          // height: 200.0.h,r
          child: _images[index] == null
              ? _nullImage
              : Image.file(_images[index], fit: BoxFit.contain),
        );
      },
      itemCount: _images.length,
      // Text(
      //   'Click to Add Step Image',
      //   style: GoogleFonts.poppins(fontSize: 14),
      // ),
    )
  ],
),
```

If the code you gave was working as you said before, this should probably work.